# Where should I put interfaces and implementations

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I have `Domain` assembly and `SqlServerRepository` assembly.

`SqlServerRepository` assembly has a reference on `Domain` assembly, `Domain` assembly doesn't have reference on other assemblies.

`Domain` assembly has interface `IRepository` (and others for repository), because domain logic works only with interface types and doesn't think about concrete types.

`SqlServerRepository` assembly implements interface `IRepository` (which is contained in the `Domain` assembly).

And it's ok, I can mock `IRepository`, can use `OracleRepository` implementation and another...

But I think I have some architecture problem...

1. `SqlServerRepository` can't work without the `Domain` assembly
2. On another hand, if I put interfaces in `SqlServerRepository` assembly, the `Domain` will not work without `SqlServerRepository` assembly, and if I create `OracleServerRepository` assembly, I must use `SqlServerRepository` too, because I put the interfaces in the `SqlServerRepository` and `Domain` alredy uses them.
3. Where should I map database objects to domain? In the `SqlServerRepository` or in the `Domain` assembly?

I thought about an assembly which contains only interfaces, and `Domain` and `SqlServerRepository` reference it, but I think it is overhead for my project (microservice)

So, what must I do?

Comment: I'd think that a common project that simply contained your necessary `interfaces` would be the best method. This would allow you to only depend on the common project from `Domain` and vise-versa from the `Repository`. This would, from what I can tell from your question, fully decouple your domain logic from repository logic, although it depends if you wish to have the overhead of managing another project. But I would say that the overhead is worth being fully decoupled.

Comment: I usually had a `Core-Contract`/`Core-Implementation` pairs of projects and used a DI tool to bring it all together. My goal was to avoid dependencies within the implementation projects. This kept it quite clean.

Comment: If you *really* want to decouple `SqlServerRepository` from `IRepository`, you can remove the dependency and use an [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) in between. However this is overkill and I definitely would *not* recommend it. The [answer by jgauffin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35986972/446278) is just fine.

Comment: I link them in wcf service use Ninject, i know how to separate them, but don't know where is i must put them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The repository interfaces belong in the domain (or rather where your services are, but they are typically part of the domain).

The reason is that the repository contracts are created and driven from functionality that the domain need. Without the domain you would not have any repositories.

> SqlServerRepository can't work without the Domain assembly

Correct. And as I stated above. You would not have a `SqlServerRepository` if it weren't for the functionality required by the domain.

> Where should I map database objects to domain? In the `SqlServerRepository` or in the `Domain` assembly?

In the repository assembly as it's an implementation detail for the specific data layer abstraction. If you had put them in the domain, the domain would have been forced to have knowledge about implementation details of every persistence layer that you are using (like oracle, sqlserver, files or whatever).

Nothing says that SQL Server and Oracle should persist the information using the same database schema. Tables, views etc might vary depending on the pros/cons that the DB engine has.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you implement things using ports and adapters [Hexagonal architecture]. Following assembly can work for microservices

1. Core.Domain : You can put all domain objects here.
2. Common.ServiceContracts : It can contain all the service contracts for different services.
3. MyService : It has the service implementation class. It will also have the interfaces for infrastructure. Infrastructure could be database, logging etc. You can expose interface to convert domain to infrastructure objects e.g. IDomain1Mapper.
4. Infrastructure : It can have class like SQLDomain1Mapper, OracleDomain1Mapper and so on. They all will implement IDomain1Mapper. Same is the case for the other domain classes.

MyService assembly will refer to Common.ServiceContracts, Infrastructure and Core.Domain.

You can mock any repository/domain in the MyService assembly as per wish. Service consumer can consume MyService assembly.